# Read lines from compressed text files

Tags: python, compression, gzip, large-files, compressed-files

Is it possible to read a line from a gzip-compressed text file using Python without extracting the file completely? I have a `text.gz` file which is around 200 MB. When I extract it, it becomes 7.4 GB. And this is not the only file I have to read. For the total process, I have to read 10 files. Although this will be a sequential job, I think it will a smart thing to do it without extracting the whole information. How can this be done using Python? I need to read the text file line-by-line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read from a gzip file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902540/read-from-a-gzip-file-in-python)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you tried using [gzip.GzipFile](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile)?  Arguments are similar to `open`.

Comment: I guess `gzip.GzipFile(file_name)` will not give the expected result, at least in Python 3+. The first thing I see in `GzipFile.__init__` in Python 3.9 library is `if mode and ('t' in mode or 'U' in mode): raise ValueError(...)`, and its `readlines()` returns `list[bytes]`.

Answer (score 148):

Using [gzip.GzipFile](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile):

```
import gzip

with gzip.open('input.gz','rt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print('got line', line)
```

Note: `gzip.open(filename, mode)` is an alias for `gzip.GzipFile(filename, mode)`.
I prefer the former, as it looks similar to `with open(...) as f:` used for opening uncompressed files.

Answer (score 55):

You could use the standard gzip module in python. Just use:

```
gzip.open('myfile.gz')
```

to open the file as any other file and read its lines.

More information here: [Python gzip module](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html)

Comment: out of curiosity does this load the entire file to memory? Or is it smart enough to load lines as needed?

Comment: @Sachin_ruk this doesn't load the file it just opens it. In order to actually load the data from file you need to do ```f.readline()`` to read line at a time. Or ``f.readlines(N)`` where ``N`` is the number of lines you want to read.

Answer (score 7):

The gzip library (obviously) uses `gzip`, which can be a bit slow. You can speed things up with a system call to [pigz](https://zlib.net/pigz/), the parallelized version of `gzip`. The downsides are you have to install `pigz` and it will take more cores during the run, but it is much faster and not more memory intensive. The call to the file then becomes `os.popen('pigz -dc ' + filename)` instead of `gzip.open(filename,'rt')`. The pigz flags are `-d` for decompress and `-c` for stdout output which can then be grabbed by `os.popen`.

The following code take in a file and a number (1 or 2) and counts the number of lines in the file with the different calls while measuring the time the code takes. Defining the following code in the `unzip-file.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
import time
import gzip

def local_unzip(obj):
    t0 = time.time()
    count = 0
    with obj as f:
        for line in f:
            count += 1
    print(time.time() - t0, count)

r = sys.argv[1]
if sys.argv[2] == "1":
    local_unzip(gzip.open(r,'rt'))
else:
    local_unzip(os.popen('pigz -dc ' + r))
```

Calling these using `/usr/bin/time -f %M` which measures the maximum memory usage of the process on a 28G file we get:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M ./unzip-file.py $file 1
(3037.2604110240936, 1223422024)
5116

$ /usr/bin/time -f %M ./unzip-file.py $file 2
(598.771901845932, 1223422024)
4996
```

Showing that the system call is about five times faster (10 minutes compared to 50 minutes) using basically the same maximum memory. It is also worth noting that depending on what you are doing per line reading in the file might not be the limiting factor, in which case the option you take does not matter.