# Error while unzipping a .gz file in python

Tags: python, compression, gzip, extract

I am trying to extract a file from inside a .gz file (or unzip it? don't really know the right nomenclature here) using python 3.8 (tried 3.7 too) and the **gzip** library on Windows, but I am getting the following error:

```
gzip.BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b'\r\n')
```

Here's the file, so the error is reproducible (it's a publicly available file):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2cs9ik9nj2tfijh/15_07_U_2020-01-24.CAT.gz?dl=0

In order to extract it, I am using the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028815/how-to-unzip-gz-file-using-python). The code is:

```
import gzip
import shutil
with gzip.open('15_07_U_2020-01-24.CAT.gz', 'rb') as f_in:
    with open('file.txt', 'wb') as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

Also, using code from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902540/read-from-a-gzip-file-in-python), I can read and see the content of the file:

```
for data in gzip.GzipFile(file):
    print(data)
```

Here, I get the same error **after printing** the whole file.

So, it seems that the symbols '\r\n' that are at the end of the file are causing the error. But how can I deal with this? Can I ignore this error, or remove the symbols somehow?

By the way, I can extract the file with WinRAR or 7z without troubles.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by extracting the file using `gzip` and logging the exception encountered. In my case, the exception didn't affect the final result and the extraction was done correctly.

**Update python 3.10**: there seems to be a [regression in Python 3.10](https://bugs.python.org/issue45475) that prevents `gzip` from working correctly (this is completely unrelated with the exception I was getting for my particular file).

This regression causes the following code:

```
for data in gzip.GzipFile(file):
    print(data)
```

to throw the following error:

```
ValueError: readline of closed file
```