# Strings are read incomplete after opening gzip files with fs.open() method

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, fs

File format: GZIP,
Stored in: GCP Storage

When I read the file with this piece of code:

```
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='myproject',token='mytoken')
with fs.open(file,'rt') as f:
   file_tmp = pd.read_csv(f, sep=",", header=0)
   print(file_tmp)
```

Some string fields come incomplete.

User A - IDFV (expected to be read): C305F2DB-56FC-404F-B6C1-BC52E0B680D8

User A - IDFV (actually read): C3

I have also tried the csv.reader() method, but same results. The only way that these fields come incomplete is when I do the import from GCS Storage to BigQuery.

Please I appreciate your insights on how to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: look at gzip module and also the file is binary in your example you are opening it in text mode

Comment: thanks! will try now

Comment: Try opening the file with the gzip library, as described in this [community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13083308/12857703) and it should work.

Comment: @gonzathegreat Did the solutions shared above fixed the issue you were facing?