# Python: How to read from compressed json .gz file and write to json file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I want to read from compressed .json.gz file and write its decoded file into .json file

.json.gz files:

- data/sample1.gz
- data/sample2.gz

write to .json files

- data/sample1.json
- data/sample2.json

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902540/read-from-a-gzip-file-in-python

Comment: No it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Do you need to use Spark in your solution? I noticed you tagged pyspark, but the question itself doesn't mention it at all.

Comment: yes, I have a directory containing .gz file. I need to read it into spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a requirement where I have a list of compressed json .gz files. I need to uncompress it and convert it back to json files with the same file name. Below mentioned code is working.

Place this script in the folder containing .gz files and run it using python3. It will work.

file: **script.py**

```
import gzip
import os

def get_file_names_by_extension(path = ".", file_extension = ".gz"):
    file_names = []
    for x in os.listdir(path):
        if x.endswith(file_extension):
            file_names.append(x)
    return file_names

def write_file(data, destination_path, file_name, encoding = "utf-8"):
    output_file_name = "/".join([destination_path, file_name])
    print(output_file_name)
    with open(output_file_name, "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(data.encode(encoding))

def decompress_files(files, destination_path, output_format = ".json", encoding = "utf-8"):
    for file in files:
        _file = gzip.GzipFile(file, "rb")
        content = _file.read()
        content = content.decode(encoding)
        output_file_name = "".join([file.split(".")[0], output_format])
        write_file(content, destination_path, output_file_name, encoding)

        
files = get_file_names_by_extension(path=".", file_extension=".gz")
decompress_files(files, ".", ".json")
```

Answer (score 0):

Pyspark can infer that the json files are gzipped from the file name. You can read the data then write it back without any compression to get the results you want. The benefit of doing this in Spark is that it can use multiple workers to read/write the data in parallel, especially if the data is in S3.

```py
df = spark.read.json("data/")
df.write.json("data/", mode="append", compression="none")
```