# How to get column names from a gzipped file python

Tags: python, csv, file, gzip

I have a file "my_file.csv.gz"
which I've opened using:

```
file = gzip.open("my_file.csv.gz", mode = "r")
```

How can I get the column names from this result? Do I have to do file.read()?
When I log out what *file* is using `logger.info(f"file: {file}")`  I get

```
<gzip _io.TextIOWrapper encoding='UTF-8' 0x7fc31958faf0>
```

and I'm not really sure what to do with this result. Thanks!

Comment: You can treat that like a file.  Pass it anywhere you would pass a file object.

Comment: Have you tried just passing the TextIOWrapper instance you got to `csv.reader` ? It does not seem to be more complicated than that.

Comment: Duplicate, look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902540/read-from-a-gzip-file-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I get gzipped files a lot for work. I like using Pandas to read the files into a dataframe using [pd.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and specifying the compression type as `gzip`. Not sure about your files but mine also have `|` as a separator rather than the default `,` so I need to specify that as well.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv.gz', compression='gzip', sep='|') #might be a different separator in your case
```