# Numpy converts scientific notation to nan while reading CSV

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nan

I encountered a problem while reading a CSV file with np.genfromtxt. All the records in CSV are in scientific notation, yet whilst reading the file with np.genfromtxt every item in the array is 'nan'.

An example row from CSV: 1.02E+02;1.64E+00

```
In [1]: read = np.genfromtxt('13G-mapa-0001.CSV', delimiter=';')
In [2]: read
Out[2]:
array([[nan, nan],
   [nan, nan],
   [nan, nan],
   ...,
   [nan, nan],
   [nan, nan],
   [nan, nan]])
```

Full file:

```
1,204619e+002;1,639486e+000 
1,214262e+002;1,623145e+000 
1,223904e+002;1,607553e+000 
1,233547e+002;1,592153e+000 
1,243189e+002;1,576472e+000 
1,252832e+002;1,560220e+000 
1,262474e+002;1,543355e+000 
1,272117e+002;1,526069e+000 
1,281759e+002;1,508706e+000 
1,291402e+002;1,491635e+000 
1,301044e+002;1,475144e+000 
1,310686e+002;1,459387e+000 
1,320329e+002;1,444416e+000
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, using a csv with only your example row, it works (returns: `array([102.  ,   1.64])`)

Comment: please can you add the file to your question. This will help others in future.

Answer (score 1):

your delimiter must be a comma ',' not a semi-colon ';'

EDIT: The issue is there are commas too such as 1,25e+00 which needs to be parsed separately

```
def genfromtxt(file):
  from io import BytesIO
  with open(file, 'r') as f:
    lines = ' '.join([s.replace(',', '.') for s in f.readlines()])
  return np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(lines.encode('utf-8')), delimiter=';', dtype=np.float32)
```

This is my solution

Comment: I don't think that's true. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140999/csv-with-comma-or-semicolon

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that, this brings me to another problem, is there a way to convert every coma to a dot in readings done by genfromtxt?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22972118/6671176), you can do the following to convert your comma decimal:

```
def conv(x):
    return x.replace(',', '.').encode()

read = np.genfromtxt((conv(x) for x in open("x.csv")), delimiter=';')

>>> read
array([[120.4619  ,   1.639486],
       [121.4262  ,   1.623145],
       [122.3904  ,   1.607553],
       [123.3547  ,   1.592153],
       [124.3189  ,   1.576472],
       [125.2832  ,   1.56022 ],
       [126.2474  ,   1.543355],
       [127.2117  ,   1.526069],
       [128.1759  ,   1.508706],
       [129.1402  ,   1.491635],
       [130.1044  ,   1.475144],
       [131.0686  ,   1.459387],
       [132.0329  ,   1.444416]])
```

Answer (score 1):

A modern, fast and versatile way to do that is provided by [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) :

```
import pandas as pd
table=pd.read_csv('data.csv',sep=';',decimal=',',header=None)
arr=table.values
```

for

```
array([[ 120.4619  ,    1.639486],
       [ 121.4262  ,    1.623145],
       [ 122.3904  ,    1.607553],
       [ 123.3547  ,    1.592153],
       [ 124.3189  ,    1.576472],
       [ 125.2832  ,    1.56022 ],
       [ 126.2474  ,    1.543355],
       [ 127.2117  ,    1.526069],
       [ 128.1759  ,    1.508706],
       [ 129.1402  ,    1.491635],
       [ 130.1044  ,    1.475144],
       [ 131.0686  ,    1.459387],
       [ 132.0329  ,    1.444416]])
```

[`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) offers more high level options than `genfromtxt`.