# loading the .dat.gz data opened in python into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, gzip

I have a file with .dat.gz extension .I have tried to load all the data contained in the file into an an object .Now I want to load it into a dataframe to work on its calculations. I have tried some steps shown in the shared screenshot.Kindly suggest what I can try for it.I tried opening this file from the cmd also but it failed.[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is a comma-delimited file, not space-delimited or tab-delimited?  You specified `sep=','`. Did you try `sep=' '` (space between quotes) or `sep='\t'`?  Also, it does not look there is a header in the file, so `header=` should be `None`, not `1`, and you should add the `names=` parameter to provide column names.

Comment: Thanks AlexK for the suggestion.I tried doing what you said.I am getting an error like this:ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 228 fields in line 9, saw 231......and also I don't know the names becoz this file is not opening.

Comment: Search Stack Overflow if you are running into new issues. 
 Here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data) on the error you are getting.

Comment: For reading compressed files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566558/python-read-lines-from-compressed-text-files

Answer (score 0):

The file is unable to be opened directly into notebook even after using read_fwf with column names.So just extracted the file  into .dat format using the external software named peazip and then loaded it into dataframe by using the pd.read_fwf("file name") with names=[column names]